# jstl foreach request response is ArrayList but ${} is string

Tags: java, servlets, foreach, jstl

listCurrencies thinks that it is a string in jsp code but request attribute has it as an ArrayList Type... the foreach therefore doesn't work. Help!

Servlet Method

```
protected void listCurrency(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
       throws ServletException, IOException {
    currencies = new Currencies();
    ArrayList<String> c = (ArrayList<String>) currencies.getCurrencyList();
    request.setAttribute("listCurrencies", c);

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/BrokerIndex.jsp");
    dispatcher.include(request, response); 
}
```

JSP Code

```
 <form action="brokerServlet" method = "Post">
<select name="currency">
    <c:forEach items="${listCurrencies}" var="cur">
        <option value="${cur}"                                        
            <c:if test="${cur eq selectedCurId}">Currency</c:if>
                            >
                        ${cur} </option>
                        </c:forEach>
     </select>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Why do you need to cast? What does `getCurrencyList()` return?

Comment: Try this. _In Post method_: `List<String> testC = Arrays.asList("cur1", "cur2", "cur3"); ` `request.setAttribute("listCurrencies_TEST", testC);`. _And in JSP_: `<c:forEach items="${listCurrencies_TEST}" var="cur"> ` `Currency: ${cur}<br>`  `</c:forEach>`.

Comment: I don't. With or without that cast I'm still getting a string in the jsp. That was just there in an attempt to force it!

Comment: @prasad_ I tried this and the same thing happens, ${cur} is null

Comment: I couldn't reply earlier (I am mostly off the net over the Weekend). I think  you should post the code for the POST method in your question. I had tried the code (from my earlier comment) - it works. It is difficult to tell from what is  exactly wrong from what is posted in your question as of now - I can make few guesses. I suggest you post all the code from your servlet and the JSP - if possible. Also, try a simpler example using a list of strings as request attribute and try to show the list contents in the JSP.